# How to obtain a font file path in c#?

Tags: c#, fonts, filepath

I have to assign to a string variable the path of a font selected through the FontDialog.

How can I accomplish this task?

```
string fontTextPath = fontDialog.Font // and then?
```

Or are there other methods?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/); can you explain what you think a “font file path” is and what you are going to use it for?

Comment: ok, simple. I want  to obtain a file path for example  "c:\windows\fonts\arial.ttf" .I need it to assign it to a string variable to use as a variable parameter in ffmpeg drawtext. Maybe I'm not very clear but i'm not english, sorry!

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure about that ffmpeg need path of the font and not the name of it ?
Most of the time components and libraries use the name of the font or it's object and work by it.

if the component need font name or font object it's so simple as something like :

```
DrawText('Sample Text, fontDialog1.Font);
```

but if you really need to get the path of the selected font in FontDialog :

```
private List<string> GetFilesForFont(string fontName)
{
    var fontNameToFiles = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

    foreach (var fontFile in Directory.GetFiles(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Fonts)))
    {
        var fc = new PrivateFontCollection();

        if (File.Exists(fontFile))
            fc.AddFontFile(fontFile);

        if ((!fc.Families.Any()))
            continue;

        var name = fc.Families[0].Name;

        // If you care about bold, italic, etc, you can filter here.
        if (! fontNameToFiles.TryGetValue(name, out var files))
        {
            files = new List<string>();
            fontNameToFiles[name] = files;
        }

        files.Add(fontFile);
    }

    if (!fontNameToFiles.TryGetValue(fontName, out var result))
        return null;

    return result;
}
```

and use it this way :

```
    if (fontDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string fontName = fontDialog1.Font.Name;
        var fontFiles = GetFilesForFont(fontName);
    }
```

Comment: Could get the path like `GetFilesForFont(fontName)[0]`, this method is very helpful, should select as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using an OpenFileDialog because your supplied code is using an object called fontDialog...

```
using (OpenFileDialog fontDialog = new OpenFileDialog())
{
    DialogResult result = fontDialog.ShowDialog();
    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string file = fontDialog.FileName;
    }
}
```

Comment: No, actually i'm using a fontdialog object not openfile dialog. however, I look at what you've posted to me can make me comfortable! thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You can index the fonts folder, mapping each font's face (its name and style) to the file name. WPF's `GlyphTypeface` provides information from a TrueType or OpenType font file.

```cs
var fontPathsByFace = new Dictionary<(string, FontStyle), string>();
foreach (var path in Directory.GetFiles(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Fonts), "*.?tf")) {
    var glyph = new GlyphTypeface(new Uri(path));
    var name = glyph.FamilyNames[CultureInfo.CurrentCulture];
    var style = (glyph.Weight == FontWeights.Bold ? FontStyle.Bold : 0) | (glyph.Style == FontStyles.Italic ? FontStyle.Italic : 0);
    fontPathsByFace.Add((name, style), path);
}
```

Then look up the font by name and style:

```cs
var path = fontPathsByFace[("Arial", FontStyle.Bold)];
```